# How to use C++ Builder OPENARRAY in a custom function

Tags: c++, c++builder, variadic-functions

I would like to use `OPENARRAY` (or an alternative, if you have one) to pass multiple placeholder variables into my function. I know that it can be used for `String::Format` in this way:

```
UnicodeString Text1 = "abc";
int Num2 = 1;
String::Format("Some %s and %d", OPENARRAY(TVarRec, (Text1, Num2));
```

What I would like is to use Text1 and Text2 variables in something like this:

```
MyFunction("Some %Txt1 and %Num2", OPENARRAY(TVarRec, ("%Txt1", Text1, "%Num2", Num2));
```

Or perhaps:

```
MyFunction(OPENARRAY(TVarRec, ("Some %Txt1 and %Num2", "%Txt1", Text1, "%Num2", Num2));
```

So it would accept the text and replace the placeholder variables with appropriate variable content.

What I don't know is how do I read OPENARRAY parameter content from MyFunction.

So the function would look like:

```
UnicodeString MyFunction(UnicodeString Txt, ?WHAT-HERE?)
{
// read openarray here and replace vars
return StringReplace(Txt, ?WHAT-HERE?);
}
```

So I don't know how do I accept the OPENARRAY variables. Also, if you have an alternative solution to passing placeholder, variable in similar manner (without the use of C++11), that would also be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing a Delphi-style Open Array to a function, two things are actually passed:

- a pointer to the first element of the array
- the index of the last element of the array (NOT the length of the array, as you might expect!).

So, in your example, you can declare your function like this:

```
UnicodeString MyFunction(UnicodeString Txt, const TVarRec *Values, const int Values_High)
```

And then loop through the array using normal pointer arithmetic.

`TVarRec` can hold many different data types, so you have to look at its `VType` field to know what kind of data it is actually referencing, and then access the appropriate data field.  Some values (integers and single characters) are stored directly in the `TVarRec` itself, while others (strings and other class types) are referenced by pointer instead.

For example:

```
UnicodeString MyFunction(UnicodeString Txt, const TVarRec *Values, const int Values_High)
{
    if (((Values_High + 1) % 2) != 0)
        throw Exception("uneven number of values!");

    for (int index = 0; index <= Values_High; index += 2)
    {
        String OldValue, NewValue;

        switch (Values[index].VType)
        {
            case vtString:
                OldValue = * static_cast<const ShortString*>(Values[index].VString);
                break;

            case vtPChar:
                OldValue = Values[index].VPChar;
                break;

            case vtPWideChar:
                OldValue = Values[index].VPWideChar;
                break;

            case vtAnsiString:
                OldValue = * static_cast<const AnsiString*>(Values[index].VAnsiString);
                break;

            case vtWideString:
                OldValue = * static_cast<const WideString*>(Values[index].VWideString);
                break;

            case vtUnicodeString:
                OldValue = * static_cast<const UnicodeString*>(Values[index].VUnicodeString);
                break;

            default:
                throw Exception("illegal value type at index %d!", ARRAYOFCONST(( index )) );
        }

        switch (Values[index+1].VType)
        {
            case vtInteger:
                NewValue = Values[index+1].VInteger;
                break;

            case vtBoolean:
                NewValue = Values[index+1].VBoolean;
                break;

            case vtChar:
                NewValue = Values[index+1].VChar;
                break;

            case vtExtended:
                NewValue = * static_cast<const Extended*>(Values[index+1].VExtended);
                break;

            case vtString:
                NewValue = * static_cast<const ShortString*>(Values[index+1].VString);
                break;

            case vtPChar:
                NewValue = Values[index+1].VPChar;
                break;

            case vtWideChar:
                NewValue = Values[index+1].VWideChar;
                break;

            case vtPWideChar:
                NewValue = Values[index+1].VPWideChar;
                break;

            case vtAnsiString:
                NewValue = * static_cast<const AnsiString*>(Values[index+1].VAnsiString);
                break;

            case vtCurrency:
                NewValue = * static_cast<const Currency*>(Values[index+1].VCurrency);
                break;

            case vtVariant:
                NewValue = * static_cast<const Variant*>(Values[index+1].VVariant);
                break;

            case vtWideString:
                NewValue = * static_cast<const WideString*>(Values[index+1].VWideString);
                break;

            case vtInt64:
                NewValue = * static_cast<const __int64*>(Values[index+1].VInt64);
                break;

            case vtUnicodeString:
                NewValue = * static_cast<const UnicodeString*>(Values[index+1].VUnicodeString);
                break;

            default:
                throw Exception("illegal value type at index %d!", ARRAYOFCONST(( index )) );
        }

        Txt = StringReplace(Txt, OldValue, NewValue, TReplaceFlags() << rfReplaceAll);
    }

    return Txt;
}
```

```
MyFunction("Some %Txt1 and %Num2", OPENARRAY(TVarRec, ("%Txt1", Text1, "%Num2", Num2)) );
```

On a side note, when a function takes an open array of `TVarRec` values, you should use the `ARRAYOFCONST()` macro instead of the `OPENARRAY()` macro directly, eg:

```
String::Format("Some %s and %d", ARRAYOFCONST(( Text1, Num2 )) );
```

```
MyFunction("Some %Txt1 and %Num2", ARRAYOFCONST(( "%Txt1", Text1, "%Num2", Num2 )) );
```

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed reply - you've practically created the whole function for me, much more than I asked for - but still - amazing work and great answer! Also, much appreciate the `ARRAYOFCONST` tip!

Comment: The `sysopen.h` header file contains several useful macros for dealing with open array parameters: `OPENARRAY()`, `ARRAYOFCONST()`, `ARRAYSIZE()`, `EXISTINGARRAY()`, and `SLICE()`.